# Trying to create and xml attribute for a parent node while using XMLSerialization

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

I am using the XMLSerialization class in .Net to serialize an object to XML.  In trying to set up a specific layout for the XML but am struggling to figure out how to add an attribute to the parent node in collection of elements (specifically the ProgrammingLanguages element below):

```
 <Devloper>
      <FirstName IsNew="true">John</FirstName>
      <LastName IsNew="true">Doe</LastName>
      <ProgrammingLanguages>
        <LanguageType isNew="true">VB</LanguageType>
        <LanguageType isNew="false">C#</LanguageType>
      </ProgrammingLanguages>
    </Devloper>
```

I can add an attribute (IsNew) to a element if there isn't a hierarchy to that data such as the FirstName and LastName elements, but how do I add a attribute to the ProgrammingLanguages element and NOT the LanguageType element when the parameter being used is a list.

Above is the XML output I am getting from using the code below but I would like the results to be as follows.:

```
<Devloper>
  <FirstName IsNew="true">John</FirstName>
  <LastName IsNew="true">Doe</LastName>
  **<ProgrammingLanguages isNew="true">**
    <LanguageType>VB</LanguageType>
    <LanguageType>C#</LanguageType>
  </ProgrammingLanguages>
</Devloper>
```

My Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim dev As New Devloper
        dev.FirstName.text = "John"
        dev.FirstName.IsNew = True

        dev.LastName.text = "Doe"
        dev.LastName.IsNew = True

        Dim l1 As New LanguageType
        l1.text = "VB"
        l1.isnew = True

        Dim l2 As New LanguageType
        l2.text = "C#"
        l2.isnew = False
        dev.ProgrammingLanguages.AddRange({l1, l2})

        dev.toXML()
    End Sub
End Class

<Serializable> Public Class Devloper
    Public Sub toXML()
        Dim mySerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Devloper))
        Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("d:\myFileName.xml")
        mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, Me)
        myWriter.Close()
    End Sub

    Public FirstName As New helperClass
    Public LastName As New helperClass
    Public ProgrammingLanguages As New List(Of LanguageType)
End Class

Public Class helperClass
    <XmlText> Public text As String
    <XmlAttribute> Public IsNew As Boolean
End Class

Public Class LanguageType
    <XmlText> Public text As String
    <XmlAttribute> Public isNew As Boolean
End Class
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it in c# i think it will help you 
what i got in xml file was:

```
<firstClass Name="ABC">
  <CustomerPhones Count="2">
    <phone Number="123" Address="Home" />
    <phone Number="456" Address="Work" />
  </CustomerPhones>
</firstClass>
```

I created these classes:

```
public class firstClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Phones CustomerPhones { get; set; }
    }
public class Phones
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Count { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("phone")]
        public List<Phone> phones { get; set; }
    }
public class Phone
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Number { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```